# oracle DB - joining with a messy string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to join two tables in oracle:

Table 1

```
Jira ID|bugz url(string)
-------|---------
1234   |http-url-897654
1235   |http-url-158974
1236   |http-url-158975\nhttp-url-158972
```

Table 2

```
BUG_ID(int)|Stuff
-------|---------
897654 |Stuff
158974 |Stuff
158975 |Stuff
```

I want to join Table 2 to Table 1 using a best effort match. The BUG_ID will ALWAYS be 7 numeric digits and the URL in Table 1 is a string, but I am happy to only use "valid" strings which is a URL ending in:

```
https://example.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1958615 <-- this is the BUG_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are looking for *url*, say

```
  http(s): ... ?id=7_DIGITS_BUG_NUMBER
```

you can try *regular expression*, [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) in case of Oracle:

```
   select ...
     from table1 join table2
       on regexp_substr(table1.bugz_url, '^https?:.*\?id=([0-9]{7})$', 1, 1, null, 1) =
           to_char(table2.bug_id)
```

Comment: This worked, and will probably bet the the regular substring match if people end up putting in trialling spaces and url anchors `#c4` for example, Thank you!

Comment: @Rqomey: in case of *trailing spaces*, just trim them: `rtrim(...)` before `substr` or `regexp_substr` call. Regular expressions are useful if you want to ensure that you're dealing with url and, not, say, `123=4567890`

Comment: Accepted this one as it is a bit more robust, same performance on my system, and can handle a bit more mess!

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
select ...
  from table1
       join table2
            on substr(table1.bugz_url, -7) = to_char(table2.bug_id);
```

Comment: That worked! Perfectly simple! I was over thinking it because the bugz url string isn't validated there is a bunch of crap in there, but yep, if I just do it this way it either matches or doesn't! Thank you! Ha, I was on my way to creating temporary rows using regex and everything.

Comment: I always prefer to **underthink** things!